# printfs hangs in kubernetes environment

Tags: multithreading, docker, kubernetes, printf, libc

I am debugging an app for a hang. This is running as a container in the kubernetes environment. The app is  multi threaded and implements a fuse file system.

```
 Thread 7 (Thread 0x7f631da4d700 (LWP 20)):
    #0  __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
    #1  0x00007f632ef80810 in buffered_vfprintf (s=s@entry=0x7f632f30e680 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>, format=format@entry=0x55667b5c4ebe "%s %s at %s:%d ", args=args@entry=0x7f631da4c800) at vfprintf.c:2336
    #2  0x00007f632ef7d726 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7f632f30e680 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>, format=0x55667b5c4ebe "%s %s at %s:%d ", ap=ap@entry=0x7f631da4c800) at vfprintf.c:1301
    #3  0x00007f632ef86e54 in __fprintf (stream=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>) at fprintf.c:32
    ---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---


other threads also hung in the same place


Thread 17 (Thread 0x7f62bafcd700 (LWP 208)):
#0  __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
#1  0x00007f632ef80810 in buffered_vfprintf (s=s@entry=0x7f632f30e680 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>, format=format@entry=0x55667b5c4ebe "%s %s at %s:%d ", args=args@entry=0x7f62bafcb930) at vfprintf.c:2336
#2  0x00007f632ef7d726 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7f632f30e680 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>, format=0x55667b5c4ebe "%s %s at %s:%d ", ap=ap@entry=0x7f62bafcb930) at vfprintf.c:1301
#3  0x00007f632ef86e54 in __fprintf (stream=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>) at fprintf.c:32
}

Thread 15 (Thread 0x7f62c47e0700 (LWP 151)):
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
{
#0  __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95
#1  0x00007f632ef80810 in buffered_vfprintf (s=s@entry=0x7f632f30e680 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>, format=format@entry=0x55667b5c4ebe "%s %s at %s:%d ", args=args@entry=0x7f62c47de930) at vfprintf.c:2336
#2  0x00007f632ef7d726 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7f632f30e680 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>, format=0x55667b5c4ebe "%s %s at %s:%d ", ap=ap@entry=0x7f62c47de930) at vfprintf.c:1301
#3  0x00007f632ef86e54 in __fprintf (stream=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>) at fprintf.c:32
```

I dont know much about the bugs in the kubernetes logging infrastucture . The code doesnt hang when run outside kubernetes though.

Comment: There most likely has to be at least one thread hung in a different place holding the lock, or a thread died somehow while holding the lock in question.  Less likely is some memory corruption that corrupted the lock.

Comment: Interesting and similar case of improper call to `fclose()` resulting in undefined behavior that mimics your problem:  https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3247

Comment: @AndrewHenle this is the lock in the libc printf code. So I wonder what would cause to not release the lock and have a deadlock. If this is caused by thread crashing or dying, i expected to see a crash.

Comment: How hard is this to duplicate?  Is it possible to put the process under `strace` and still duplicate the issue? (If this is some sort of race condition, putting the process under `strace` will seriously impact timing, and might make the deadlock impossible to replicate.) I'd also look into the shared objects that get linked into the process when running under kubernetes and compare that to the libraries that get pulled in when run normally.  Maybe you can kludge up some environment/directory tree combination and use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and duplicate the issue outside of kubernetes?